# How to determine the length of an array of strings in C

Tags: c

I have a function which splits a string into tokens and stores it in an array. How to determine the size of an array of strings of type `char**`?

```
ie: char **input;
```

Comment: Given only the pointer-to-pointer, you *must* have some termination rule (a finishing known-value, such as `NULL`). There is no standard way to "know" a sequence length given only a base pointer to it. Ever wonder why so many functions taking sequence pointers are also provide a `size_t` *length* ? Now you know.

Comment: The short answer is also **keep a counter** of each token. If you are doing this in function, you can pass a pointer to `size_t` and update the value with the count so that it is available back in the calling function while still allowing you to return a pointer-to-pointer-to-char. Keeping a counter also allows you to **validate** you do not assign more strings than you have allocated pointers.

Comment: @technosaurus: Actually `argv` is `NULL`-terminated; ther is no immanent need for `argc` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a variable globally and increment that variable value in the function which is splitting the string into tokens & storing into array.